# C++ template function that takes a function type with specific return type

Tags: c++, templates

I am doing some magic with templates in c++ and thought of trying something.

In this case I wrote a naive generic list implementation with a `List` Type and a `ListElement` Type that contains the data.

Now I already wrote a templated "for each call" function, that takes an arbitrary member function type of the type stored in the list with an arbitrary argument list and calls that member function on each element in the list with the given arguments:

```
template<typename function, typename ... arguments>
void for_each_call(function call, arguments ... args)
{
    for(ListElement * current = this->first; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    {
        (current->value->*call)(args ...);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that I can not "react" to the return values of the called function. Though I do NOT want to implement a `.map` functionality!

Now I want to implement a "for each call until" that calls a function upon the values in the list until a call returns "true" and then stops. For that I need to limit the functions inserted as a template parameter to functions of any type that specifically return a boolean. I typed around until the compiler stopped complaining and got this:

```
template<bool (*function), typename ... arguments>
void for_each_call_until(arguments ... args)
{
    for(ListElement * current = this->first; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    {
        if((current->value->*function)(args ...)) break;
    }
}
```

What is happening here, is this the right way, and if not, what is the right way?

EDIT: As some people recommend using functions from the std:: namespace: In these little training sessions I try to avoid the std:: like a plague, as if I would want to use std:: I would not write these little standardimplementations of stuff like lists, vectors or mappings myself but use std:: or boost::

Comment: Not really a solution, but a quick and dirty way with your original code is to assign the return value of (current->value->*call)(args) to a boolean local variable. This assignment will fail to compile unless the function actually returns a boolean, so in effect you will have limited the function to only accepting functions that return boolean. The resulting compile error is actually pretty informative if I recall correctly, something like "cannot convert a <wrong return type> to boolean."

Comment: This approach will also work if the function returns an int, which would be wrong.

Comment: Well we are talking about c++, the semantics behind a bool and an int as a return type is intertwined in ways we all do not like to think about.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik bool is in fact type-defed to int in some versions of the standard I think. If you really need this safety, what about defining your own typesafe bool enum and then only accepting functions that output members of that enum.

Comment: I don't need that safety, it was really just the best way to pass something into an "if" that I thought of, no need to think too much about that

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this approach is unnecessarily limiting:

```
(current->value->*call)(args ...);
```

If you *require* a member function, there's only a small handful of operations you can actually do. If the caller wants to do more, they're kind of screwed. Instead, generalize and pass `current->value` as the first argument:

```
template<typename function, typename ... arguments>
void for_each_call(function call, arguments ... args)
{
    for(ListElement * current = this->first; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    {
        call(current->value, args...);
    }
}
```

This works on all the cases as before - where you would pass `&Class::mem` before now instead you pass `std::mem_fn(&Class::mem)` - but now you can pass any kind of callable too.

---

Now onto your main question. You don't have to do anything different. Just use the result of `call()`:

```
template<typename function, typename ... arguments>
void for_each_call(function call, arguments ... args)
{
    for(ListElement* current = this->first; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    {
        if (call(current->value, args...)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. If the user provides a callable that doesn't return something contextually convertible to `bool`, they'll get a compile error. Why limit to just returning `bool`?

If you really do need really just `bool`, throw in a static assert:

```
template<typename function, typename ... arguments>
void for_each_call(function call, arguments ... args)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(call(this->first->value, args...)), bool>::value, "Must be bool!");
    // rest...
}
```

Note: You probably want to take your `arguments...` by reference to `const` to avoid lots of copies.

Comment: The first approach I also thought about but I get the compile error: Error: >>.*<< or >>->*<< needs to be used to call the pointer to element as function in >>call (...)<< , eg. >>(... -> *call)(...)<< . That's the reason I limited myself to member functions.

Comment: @salbeira I don't know what you're saying. Did you use [`mem_fn()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)?

Comment: When and where? And propably not because I avoid the std:: in my training sessions because if I would use std:: I would not need to write these little snippets of personal success :-P

Comment: @salbeira Where I said to in the answer. Also read the reference. Also avoiding using the standard library is pretty silly.

Comment: I do this to try to understand what and why the std:: does things. The construction of the mem_fn wrapper seems like something I would try to implement myself without 500 edge cases myself, I just tried to read the libc++ functions.h and thought "wow I do not understand anything in there, time to try this myself" --- also yeah - I do it because it is silly and fun

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this, just to show you how *member function pointers work*:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  bool test() { return true; }
};

/// The function takes a member function of a class T and its arguments.
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void for_each_call_until(bool (T::*member_function)(Args...),
                         Args&& ... args) {
  T obj;  // Instantiate an example object.
  bool rts = (obj.*member_function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  if (rts == false) {  // Check for the result of the member function
    // close
  }
  // ...
}
```

Your function could be something like:

```
template<typename... Args>
void for_each_call_until(bool (ListElement::*member_function)(Args...),
                         Args&& ... args) {
  for ( /* iteration over pointers */ ) {
    bool rts = (current->*member_function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (rts == false) {
      // break
    }
    // ...
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution involves using partial specialization to force a compilation error:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename T> struct is_bool;

template<> struct is_bool<bool> { typedef int value; };

template<typename function, typename ... arguments>
void for_each_call(function call, arguments && ... args)
{
    typedef decltype(call(std::forward<arguments>(args)...)) ret_type;

    typedef typename is_bool<ret_type>::value x;

    call(std::forward<arguments>(args)...);
}

bool foo(int, int) {}   // Compiles

// int foo(int, int) {}   // Does not compile

int main()
{
    for_each_call(foo, 4, 2);
    return 0;
}
```